# What is the difference between := and = in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, colon-equals

I have been working with Excel for a while, yet i have never read what is the difference between these two operators ("regardless of i have used both")
 `:=` and `=` in Excel VBA

Comment: I wouldn't call `:=` an "operator" - it's more like a "named argument specifier".

Comment: `call function (argument:=value)` say all arguments are optional, and there are 10, you want to pass the 5th by name, then variable setting such as and `let variable=x`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you already know, `=` is used to assign values or set objects - e.g. `i=1`

`:=` on the other hand (like Comintern mentioned), is used to to assign a value to a certain **named** argument, afaik only ever inside a method or function.

Consider the following example: you could use something like `MsgBox "Hello World", , "Title1"` - specifying `MsgBox`'s arguments in the default order - the `prompt`, the default `Buttons`-style, then the `Title`.

Alternatively, one could use `:=` to write `MsgBox Title:="Title1", prompt:="Hello world"`

Notice that

- the order of the arguments is of no importance here and
- there is no need to specify empty placeholders for default-arguments `, ,`.

Comment: `=` is also used as a boolean operator, which is why it is important not to accidentally use `=` instead of `:=` - e.g. `MsgBox Title="Title1", prompt="Hello world"` would probably equate to `MsgBox False, False` if `Option Explicit` wasn't being used.

Answer (score 4):

Let us take for example the [`Range.Find` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

> *expression*.**Find(*What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat*)**

That is a ***LOT*** of conditions to set!  But you just want a simple search of the number `2` in `Range("A1:A500")`:

Without the `:=` operator, you would have to use commas to get to any optional variables to set:

```
Range("A1:A500").Find(2, , xlValue, , , , , , )
```

With the `:=` operator, you can specify which conditions you want without delineating through all the default settings:

```
Range("A1:A500").Find(what:=2, lookin:=xlValues)
```

Comment: The only *required* argument to `Range.Find` is `What`; it's not true that you need to specify all arguments - you need to specify all arguments *that you're not providing a value for*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Clarified you would have to use commas to get through optional values.

Comment: Just to point out, in the example above, this would also function the same as the above examples: `Range("A1:A500").Find 2,, xlValues`. Which one looks more tidy is a matter of opinion.  If fewer keystroke is the goal, even this functions the same: `[A1:A500].Find 2,,-4163`.  Also, **parentheses are optional if the function is not returning a value** (Such as `MsgBox "Hi"`), and if all the rest of the parameters are blank and/or default, no further comma's need to be included (ie. `…xlValue, , , , , ,` = `…xlValue`)